# NoBrokersAvailable while creating kafka producer using kafka-python client

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, kafka-python

I have an API endpoint

```
def post():

    .....
    producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=["some ip: port"],
                             value_serializer=lambda x: dumps(x).encode('utf-8'), 
                                compression_type='gzip')
    producer.send(topic,data)
    ....
```

This endpoint is hit by many clients (more than 10,000) every 10 seconds.

This code works sometimes and fails sometimes with "**NoBrokersAvailable**" error. Since it works some times, I am assuming my kafka confugration is correct and it is related to the load.

My Kafka is a single node configuration with single partition of topic.

What can I do so that my endpoint can handle that much load.

Comment: Are you deliberately using a single broker? Kafka is a distributed system and with a single node you have no redundancy or resilience to data loss. Have you looked at your Kafka broker metrics to determine if it's over capacity? Try adding more brokers, and consider more than a single partition too

Comment: Hi @RobinMoffatt I tried your suggestions, but now I am getting error "KafkaTimeoutError: Failed to update metadata after 60.0 secs" frequently but sometimes producer.send() succeeds.